# Sharepoint Online Highlighted Content Web Part - Show files sub folder CAML Query

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, caml

Sharepoint noob here. On my sharepoint site I have a document library that has subfolders in it. I'm using the Highlighted Content webpart and would like to filter and show only files within a specific subfolder in the document library.

I feel like CAML is the only I can do this but I am unfamiliar with the syntax.

So far I have:

```
<View>
<Where>
   <Contains>
      <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
      <Value Type='Lookup'></Value>
   </Contains>
</Where>
</View>
```

But this shows the subfolders themselves.

I just need to get into the subfolder. Does anybody know how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. No idea how or why it works, I found it infuriating trial and error.

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>
    <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Subfolder/Subfolder</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

Hope this saves someone a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up if someone is using the above solution -- for Subfolder, put the EXACT subfolder name you want to pull from the document library. So for example if I have a subfolder off of documents named "TestFolder", the code should be:

```
<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
<Query>
    <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>TestFolder</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

If you have a subfolder, then "TestFolder\Subfolder" or "TestFolder\Sub folder" (yes indeed, spaces are fine) BUT if you have special characters, like an ampersand, you'd need to use whatever the CAML escape is for it.

So for an ampersand (&), you'd use:

```
"TestFolder\Sub&amp;folder"
```

Now the bigger question is -- why isn't a subfolder picker part of the Highlighted Content web part?

Anyway, hope this helps.